# How to get copy of Email Sent using Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-ses

I sent invoices via amazon SES to all my buyers every week. So usually it will be in bulk of 2k to 4k emails every week. The thing is that I need to keep proof that I have sent the invoice via mail to the customers.

I have set up ElasticSearch (Kibana) with amazon SES to store sent emails (followed these steps [Amazon SES Steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-sending-history/)) but this just store the emails sent details and not the actual email itself. For example, the data stored in Kibana is

```
{
  "_index": "SES",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "4962123782858127318231234860998905801425260929613826.2",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "eventType": "Send",
    "mail": {
      "timestamp": "2021-08-19T15:01:48.652Z",
      "source": "xxxxxxxxx@outlook.com",
      "sourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/xxxxxxxxxxx@outlook.com",
      "sendingAccountId": "xxxxxx06791",
      "messageId": "010f015b5fffb7ec-21d56945-2b90-41c3-81b2-c0ef03a0994b2-000000",
      "destination": [
        "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
      ],
      "headersTruncated": false,
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Received",
          "value": "from [192.XXX.1.11] ([45.XXX.XXX.13]) by email-smtp.amazonaws.com with SMTP (SimpleEmailService-d-0YLZJYHCB) id 4wywhmYezZnXqmVM5xEv for m.irshad.k@outlook.com; Thu, 19 Aug 2021 15:01:48 +0000 (UTC)"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "multipart/mixed; boundary=\"===============3068452615067814389==\""
        },
        {
          "name": "MIME-Version",
          "value": "1.0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Subject",
          "value": "Your Invoice - MY Company"
        },
        {
          "name": "From",
          "value": "xxxxxxxxx@outlook.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "To",
          "value": "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET",
          "value": "SentHistory"
        }
      ],
      "commonHeaders": {
        "from": [
          "xxxxxxxxx@outlook.com"
        ],
        "to": [
          "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
        ],
        "messageId": "010f015b5fffb7ec-21d56945-2b90-41c3-81b2-c0ef03a0994b2-000000",
        "subject": "Your Invoice - MY Company"
      },
      "tags": {
        "ses:operation": [
          "SendSmtpEmail"
        ],
        "ses:configuration-set": [
          "SentHistory"
        ],
        "ses:source-ip": [
          "XX.XX.231.XX"
        ],
        "ses:from-domain": [
          "outlook.com"
        ],
        "ses:caller-identity": [
          "ses-smtp-user.20234805-132544"
        ]
      }
    },
    "send": {}
  },
  "fields": {
    "mail.timestamp": [
      "2021-08-19T15:01:48.652Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

There is nothing about the body or the attachment of the Invoice PDF in this data stored. How can I store the whole content of the email be stored? Like in Gmail where can see the body and attachment of the email sent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CC or BCC recipients to your SES message?

Another option would be to send the message to SNS, and then configure SNS to send the email. SNS can send messages to multiple destinations including SES, another SNS topic, SQS queues or execute a lambda for each input message.

Comment: Using CC and BCC has its own disadvantages, gmail and outlook block emails when a certain limit is crossed. Like if I sent mails in 1000 to a single email the smtp gets an error saying recipient blocked. Is there no possibility to store the email content?

Comment: SES doesnt support storing sent email, so CC, BCC or changing your application code are your only options. I would suggest looking into the limits of your chosen destination email address provider then adjusting your sending behavior accordingly (ie  send smaller batches of emails, adding a delay between batches etc).  Also, check your SPF, DMARC and DKIM settings - they might improve deliverability. Lastly, you might be able to increase the limits on your account (for a fee) to get around this issue.